# Criterio utilizado por Office 365 para aplicar el cambio de huso horario sobre las reuniones

Tags: outlook, office365, exchangewebservices

Mi servidor crea eventos en los calendarios de personas y recursos (salas) en Office 365 de un cliente. En el último cambio de hora realizado en Brasil, nos dimos cuenta de que Office 365 no actualizó el horario de ninguno de los eventos  creados por el usuario utilizado por nuestro servidor en los calendarios de las personas y recursos de nuestro cliente. Nos llamó poderosamente la atención que a ninguno de los eventos se les haya aplicado el cambio de hora, ni siquiera a los eventos creados en personas o recursos de Brasil.

Se viene otro cambio de hora y necesito saber si Office365/Exchange aplica el cambio de hora sólo sobre los eventos creados por usuarios que pertenecen a la zona afectada por el cambio de horario u lo decide de alguna otra manera. ¿Alguien sabe cuál es el criterio utilizado por Office365/Exchange para decidir a cuáles reuniones le aplica el cambio de hora?

Agradezco inmensamente su ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

No existe algo como el cambio de hora, normalmente la hora se almacena en formato UTC, y lo que es importante es determinar de que forma vas a mostrar esa hora, de acuerdo al uso horario de cada uno de los usuarios.
Esa es la razón por la que cada usuario tiene la opción de configurar su uso horario en el perfil de office 365.

Incluso si la hora no se ha almacenado en UTC, el paso a seguir siempre será aplicar el uso horario de cada persona que se conecta.